# Is there any form to put the char array on a string and changing it again?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, char

When I put:

```
char[] chars=Texto.toCharArray();
String D= new String(chars);
```

And when i put "hello" the char gets the first letter, "h" but the String gets "hello" and I need just the "h" to put it on the condition of an if, what could i put so the String just get one letter.

Comment: This one `String D = chars[0].toString()` or `Texto.substring(0,1)`

Comment: What's your code for if condition?

Comment: if (D.equals("A"||"a") {

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do (like it was suggested in the comments):

```
String d = Textto.substring(0, 1);
// d = "h"
```

Am I missing something here ?

**EDIT**

Gathered from your comments, you want to check if the string contains a certain character, this is a way to do so:

```
if(d.contains("o")) {
    d = d + "fo";
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Well, this is very far from your original question, but going through your comments, you want to replace every occurrence of a vowel with the following pattern -> `[vowel]f[vowel]`.

Here is an (untested) app:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  {
    String d = "hello";

    for(char c : d.toCharArray()) {
        if(isVowel(c)) {
            d = replaceVowel(d, c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(d);
}

private static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    return "AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(c) != -1;
}

private static String replaceVowel(String original, char c) {
    String vowel = Character.toString(c);
    return original.replace(vowel, String.format("%1$sf%1$s",vowel));
}
```

Take a look here (*edited*):
http://ideone.com/uWpjbb

Comment: but I need that it changes, I need H,e,l,l,o

Comment: @AlbertoReyesCamacho What do you mean, can you be a bit more specific ? What exactly do you want to do with the input ?

Comment: I want to change the letters of a text enter by an user, if the text has an "o" I need to change the text to hava an "ofo" ex. The user put "Hello" I print "Hellofo"

Comment: Yes but not that is gonna change the text, IF there is a vocal on the text i need to change everyone one with the ofo, afa, efe, etc., but ex. "Hello" to Hefellofo"

Comment: @AlbertoReyesCamacho Check my edit again :) Also may I suggest you edit your question a bit and include all the details.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want, but here are a couple of guesses...

To test if a string starts with a letter:

```
if (Texto.toLowerCase().startsWith("a"))
```

To get the first letter as a String:

```
String first = Texto.substring(0, 1);
```